# Angular 4 dropdown not working using animations

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-animations

*html*

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>BackOffice</h3>
      <strong>BO</strong>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <!-- <li class="active" -->
        <li>

        <a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">  
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home "></i>
        DASHBOARD <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <div  *ngIf= show [@popOverState]="stateName"> 
          <ul class= "list-unstyled " id="homeSubmenu ">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Dashboard</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div> 
      </li>

      <li>
        <a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate "></i>
        CUSTOMERS
        </a>
        <div   [@popOverState]="stateName">
          <ul class=" list-unstyled " id="customersSubmenu ">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Customers Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Incomplete Registrations</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Locked Accounts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link "></i>
        FX
        </a>
        <div   [@popOverState]="stateName">
        <ul class="list-unstyled " id="fxSubmenu ">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">CustomerQuotes</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Transactions</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Forwards</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Limit Orders</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Trading</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Rates Matrix</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Settlements</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip "></i>
        SETTLEMENTS
        </a>
        <div   [@popOverState]="stateName">
        <ul class="list-unstyled" id="settlementsSubmenu ">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Daily Processes</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">CP Statements</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Currency Accounts</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Overdues</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascrip[t:void(0)">Direct Debits</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Unprocessed Direct Debits</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Payments</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Forward Revaluations</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Recipient Payments</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Counter Party Payments</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Cash Payment</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Recipients</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Cancellations</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Loans</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Currency Cloud</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a (click)="toggle()"  href="javascript:void(0)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send "></i>
        COMPLIANCE
        </a>
        <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
        <ul class= "list-unstyled" id="complianceSubmenu ">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Customer Applications</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">PEP And Sanctions</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Sanctions Matches</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Transaction Alerts</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Limit Requests</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">DD Approvals</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Documents</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Risk Scoring</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Transaction Monitoring Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Sanction Recipients</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">TA Recipients</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Negative List</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Negative List Removal</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Disabled Accounts</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Closed Accounts</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Declined Accounts</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">OTP Locked</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send "></i>
        REPORTING
        </a>
        <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
        <ul class="list-unstyled " id="reportingSubmenu ">
          <li><a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">BPNG Reports</a>
            <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
            <ul class="list-unstyled" id="reportingSubmenu ">
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Reporting Matrix</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Clients Reports Due</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bank Reports</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Reporting Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>      
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        <div   [@popOverState]="stateName">
        <ul class="list-unstyled" id="reportingSubmenu ">
          <li><a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">Reporting</a>
            <div  [@popOverState]="stateName">
            <ul class="list-unstyled" id="reportingSubmenu">
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Reports</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">IFTI Reports</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Company Funds</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip "></i>
        USERS
        </a>
        <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
        <ul class="list-unstyled" id="usersSubmenu">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Information</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Pending</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Permissions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip "></i>
        PREFERENCES
        </a>
        <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
        <ul class="list-unstyled " id="preferencesSubmenu ">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Integrations</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Application Preferences</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Customization</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Payment Files</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>
          PARTNERS
        </a>
        <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
        <ul class="list-unstyled" id="partnersSubmenu ">
          <li><a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">White Labels</a>
            <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="partnersSubmenu ">
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Information</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
        <ul class="list-unstyled" id="partnersSubmenu">
          <li><a (click)="toggle()" href="javascript:void(0)">Affiliates</a>
            <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
            <ul class="list-unstyled " id="partnersSubmenu ">
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Information</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
          <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";  */

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
    height: 100%;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}



i, span {
    display: inline-block;
}

---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
-----------------------------------------------------
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    top:0;
    left:0;   
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}


#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
    margin-right:  0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, #sidebar.active a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: grey;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: block;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}
#sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active > a, a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: grey;
}


a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e259';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 0.6em;
} 
 a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e260';
}


ul ul a {
    font-size: 1.5em !important;         /*sub-menu items size */
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}



a.article, a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}


.fa-caret-down {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
```

*ts file*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('popOverState', [
    state('show', style({
      opacity: 1
    })),

    state('hide', style({
      opacity: 0
    })),

    transition('show => hide', animate('1000ms ease-out')),
    transition('hide => show', animate('1000ms ease-in'))
      ])
    ]
      })


export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit {

  show = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  get stateName() {
    return this.show ? 'show' : 'hide'
  }


toggle() {
  this.show = !this.show;
}

}
```

Description: Now I am getting a sidebar with dropdown animation but there is a lot of space(padding) even if unclicked i.e. animation is absent. I want to remove this  space. 
Also on clicking on DASHBOARD, every dropdown content is shown(even clicking on DASHBOARD CUSTOMERS content are also displayed on click event., how to make states independent of each other. i.e. on single click only that particular animation must be visible.

Could anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

1) First, to remove the space, just set the padding at 0 for the `<ul>` tag :

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

2) Then, to animate a specific div you can do as follow :

- put the div name as parameter of the toggle() function
- use (@popOverState.done)="animationDone()" to be able to toggle the animation state once the animation has finished
- use *ngIf="divName==='divA'" to only show the div you want to see

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>BackOffice</h3>
            <strong>BO</strong>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li class="active">
                <a (click)="toggle('divA')" href="javascript:void(0)">DASHBOARD</a>
                <div *ngIf="divName==='divA'" [@popOverState]="stateName" (@popOverState.done)="animationDone()">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled " id="homeSubmenu ">
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a (click)="toggle('divB')" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-expanded="false">CUSTOMERS</a>
                <div *ngIf="divName==='divB'"  [@popOverState]="stateName" (@popOverState.done)="animationDone()">
                    <ul class=" list-unstyled " id="customersSubmenu ">
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Customers Information</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Incomplete Registrations</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Locked Accounts</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  show = true;
  divName = '';
  count = 0;

  constructor() { }

  get stateName() {
    return this.show ? 'show' : 'hide'
  }

  animationDone() {
    this.count++;
    if(this.count<2) {
      this.show = !this.show;
    }
  }



 toggle(myDiv) {
    this.count = 0;
    this.show = !this.show;
    if (this.divName === myDiv) {
      this.divName = '';
    } else {
      this.divName = myDiv;
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5cqin)

Comment: The html extension is shown above, adding just  padding:0 dont work for every element.
Also On first click, I want to enable dropdown using animation , it must be disabled only after another click on same.In your code it is disappearing after some time, which I dont want. 
Also I want to show caret at the corner  for each like dashboard, customers,patners etc,also it is not working. 
Also I want to underline every term.

Comment: Also how can I increase height of sidebar to entire page left side, even if I had set height as 100%, it is not taking full height.

Comment: can you please explain this if(this.count<2) {
      this.show = !this.show;
    } why count<2 ?

Comment: Did you check the Stackblitz example ? It does have the animation.

Comment: animationDone() is exectued each time the animation finishes, so if we toggle the state once the animation finishes, it will start the animation again, and so on... This is why I use the counter to do it only once

Comment: To increase the sidebar's height and make it take page's height, use **position: absolute;** for *#sidebar*

Comment: Using position:absolute in #sidebar solves the problem, but the header  i.e. dashboard disappears   What is then problem?

Comment: Yes, I saw the stackblitz example but I want to enable animation only when dashboard is clicked , on again clicking dashboard animation should hide .This is my requirement.

Comment: I edited the answer and changed the toggle() function. The Stackblitz as well, is it now what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: But I want the same using animations.In the above edited example there are no animations.means the dropdown elements should be appearing slowly one after other.

Comment: Look at my html code,   there are submenus also(dropdowns) clicking on which I must get another tab.